# Extra space to left of floated <li> items in horizontal menu

Tags: css

I am trying to create a horizontal top header with a main nav stacked on top of a sub nav.  Both navs are created using `<ul>` with floated `<li>` items.  The sub nav has extra horizontal space to the left whose cause I cannot discern (see the circled red area in the picture below):

[image: Picture of extra space]

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/W3qqh/

### Questions

1. What's causing the space?
2. How can I eliminate the space?

Also feel free to suggest other alternatives for achieving the desired menu, if you believe my approach could be improved.

### HTML

```
<div class="header">
  <div class="home-logo"><a href="/">HOME</a></div>
  <div class="main-nav">
    <ul>
      <li><a>Explore</a></li>
      <li><a>Earn</a></li>
      <li><a class="selected">Merchants</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="sub-nav">
    <ul>
      <li><a>Be Secure</a></li>
      <li><a>Get Help</a></li>
      <li><a>Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</div>
```

### CSS

```
* { box-sizing: border-box; }

.header { height:99px; width: 100%; position:fixed;}
.header.glass {opacity: 0.8; filter: alpha(opacity=80);}
.home-logo { background: pink; height:99px; width: 239px; position: fixed; }

.main-nav { color: white; position: relative; left:239px; background: #25c0df; height: 66px; line-height:66px; padding: 2px; width: 100%; text-transform: uppercase; font-size: 14px;}
.main-nav ul { height: 0; padding: 0; margin: 0; list-style-type: none; }
.main-nav li { float:left; margin-left: 40px;}
.main-nav li a.selected { border-top: 2px solid white; }
.main-nav li a:hover { border-top: 2px solid white; }

.sub-nav { font-size: 12px; color: #4ebeb2;  background: #26b; height: 33px; line-height: 33px; width: 100%; text-transform:uppercase; }
.sub-nav ul { height: 0; padding: 0; margin: 0; list-style-type: none; }
.sub-nav li { float:left; margin-left: 40px;}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `.sub-nav`, add:

```
float:left;
position:relative;
left:239px;
```

In `.main-nav`, add:

```
float:left;
```

**Solution:** You had to add `float:left;` in both `.main-nav` and `.sub-nav` and you had to add `position:relative;` and `left:239px;` because of the logo on the left.

Your problem would have been solved with just having `float:left;` but you needed to added `position` and `left`. Otherwise, your text would be behind the logo.

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/W3qqh/5/)**

**UPDATE**

In `.main-nav`, you have:

```
padding: 2px;
```

If you remove that and add `position` and `left` in `.sub-nav`, you wouldn't need `float` property.

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/W3qqh/6/)**

Comment: Thank you, the padding was it.  However, I still don't understand why the padding is pushing the subnav to the left, especially given that everything has box-sizing:border-box.  Do you know what's happening?

Comment: I think `padding` was causing an issue in your case because of the `height` on the `nav`... Check this http://jsfiddle.net/W3qqh/7/ when I increased the `height`, `padding` is not effecting anything.

Comment: I believe it's the combo of padding and line-height, since line-height is respected but begins after the padding, unlike the content which includes padding in the height calc because of border-box: http://i.imgur.com/GK9uJJ9.png.  (try adjusting padding in my OP example to 20 to reproduce that image)  I still don't understand why it's not pushing "Be secure" all the way to the right of "Merchants" though....

Comment: And one final hint: http://i.imgur.com/Zp4aVuE.png.  "Contact Us" is getting caught and pushed by the overhang from "Merchants" (I am pretty sure).  I still don't see *why* that contact us / merchants collison is dictating the positioning of the entire `<ul>`, however.

Comment: Also, try this... http://jsfiddle.net/W3qqh/9/. I added `padding:20px;` and added `float:left;` to both and it looks fine

Comment: And of course, Explore looks a little off because we changed the padding from 2 to 20

Answer (score 1):

Is this more what you were looking for: http://jsfiddle.net/W3qqh/2/?

First, set the outermost container to 100% width. Then float the three inner container `div`s and assign a width. Then apply a float to all `<li>` items (or use `display: inline-block`).

```
.header { width: 100%; }
.home-logo { width: 33.333%; float: left; background: pink; height:99px;  }
.main-nav { width: 66.666%; float: left; color: white; background: #25c0df; height: 66px; line-height:66px; padding: 2px; text-transform: uppercase; font-size: 14px;}
.sub-nav { width: 66.666%; float: left; font-size: 12px; color: #4ebeb2;  background: #26b; height: 33px; line-height: 33px; text-transform:uppercase; }
```

Comment: Nice solution, thank you.  Do you happen to know why the padding in the original was causing the extra space to the left problem? (see imbondbabys answer)

Comment: Hmm my guess is that it's because in your original fiddle, both the height and line-height of your `div.main-nav` was 66px, which would leave no room for any padding so the div beneath it gets pushed to the side. You'll notice if you reduce your `line-height` you can keep your padding and the `div.sub-nav` will fall where it should (that is, after you add the relative positioning and `left: 239px` as imbondbaby mentions. But in my example, those divs are floated so they don't get pushed around. Floated divs are ballers like that.